# How to access CSS of Angular child component with ::ng-deep

Tags: css, angular, sass, ng-deep

I'm trying to access and edit the CSS class of a child component using `::ng-deep`. I have tried different versions of the provided code below but I was unable to access the CSS. The structure of the HTML component is as follows:

[image]

This is how I'm trying to access the CSS from the parent component and change the `grid-template-columns` property of the class:

```css
::ng-deep{
  app-operator-filter{
    .header-logos-card{
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct syntax for achieving this? I'm also open to other suggestions for accessing child components as I've read that `::ng-deep` is not reliable and could be deprecated soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution to the problem is this:

```
:host ::ng-deep app-operator-filter{
  .header-logos-card {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr) !important;
  }
}
```

!important was a crucial addition as the changes were being overwritten without it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `::ng-deep` pseudo-class to any CSS rule will completely breaks the **view-encapsulation** for that rule and it becomes a global style. So, try to use it with `:host` as Angular official [Doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) suggests.

> Applying the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely
> disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with `::ng-deep`
> applied becomes a global style. In order to scope the specified style
> to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include
> the :host selector before `::ng-deep`. If the `::ng-deep` combinator is
> used without the `:host` pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into
> other components.

So, try something like this:

```css
:host ::ng-deep app-operator-filter {
  .header-logos-card {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work

```
::ng-deep .header-logos-card {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`::ng-deep` will be deprecated in future yes. An alternative would be to import the CSS/SCSS file from the child.

parent-component.css

```
.header-logos-card {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

child-component.css

```
@import './path/to/parent-component.css';
```

More about Angular css imports [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#css-imports).

Answer (score 1):

The problem behind ::ng-deep is that it makes it a global selector, to prevent that you need always use :host before it.

According documentation:

> Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style. In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep. If the ::ng-deep combinator is used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into other components.

So correct answer would be:

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .header-logos-card {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    }
  }
}
```

Or alternatively importing it styles from child:

```
@import './path/to/parent-component.css';
```

and than using it like this:

```
:host {    
  .header-logos-card {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ng deep is deprecated don't use it. Instead use both root level and component level sass. It works much easier.  I have articles on this if you are interested.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg

Answer (score 0):

1. In the app-parent.component.ts file set viewEncapsoluation to none.

   ```
   import { Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent-selector',
      templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app-parent.component.css'],
      encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
   })
   ```
2. In the app-parent.component.css file wrap the child css class by the child selector.

   ```
   app-operator-filter {
     .header-logos-card {
       grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
     }
   }
   ```